# Variance of Wiener processes in Geometric Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

The analytical solution to the Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) SDE is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Geometric_Brownian_motion&oldid=1121902158#Solving_the_SDE)

$
S_t = S_0 \exp( (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma W_t )
$

where $W_t$ is a Wiener process. One of the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process) of a Wiener process $W_t$ is that

$
Var( W_{t+u} - W_t ) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, u)
$

A simple implementation used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Geometric_Brownian_motion&oldid=1121902158#Simulating_sample_paths) to generate realizations of the GBM uses

```
x = np.exp(
    (mu - sigma ** 2 / 2) * dt
    + sigma * np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), size=(len(sigma), n)).T
)
```

That is, the $W_t$ component is sampled from $\mathcal{N}(0, \delta_t^2)$, where $\delta_t$ is a constant.

But under the above implementation, it seems to me that the variance is set to be fixed in time to be $\delta_t$ and doesn't satisfy the above property.

Am I missing something? For different realizations of GBM, how can you generate $W_t$ that satisfies the above condition?

Comment: What is your question precisely, and what do you think $x$ is?

Comment: My question is as stated in the post: "For different realizations of GBM, how can you generate $W_t$ that satisfies the above condition?" $x$ in in the snippet above is meant to be the un-scaled GBM realization, but as I noted in the original post, it doesn't satisfy the Wiener process variance property.

Comment: What does not satisfy the property, and which property is not satisfied? So far it's not clear

Comment: The Wiener process property is $Var(W_{t+u}-W_t)  \sim \mathcal{N}(0, u)$. In the snippet, $W_t$ is sampled from $\mathcal(0, \delta_t^2)$ so the variance is constant in time so the property is violated. This is all explained in the original question.

Comment: Variance of the Wiener process is constant in time, yes. It only depends on the length of the interval, over which the increment is taken. I don't get what's the problem here.

Comment: Does $Var( W_{t+u} - W_t ) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, u)$ not imply that it should be a linearly increasing function of time?

Comment: Which time? $u$ here is the length of the interval, $dt$ in your snippet. And $t$ is the running time with respect to which you simulate. The variance does depend on $u = dt$ and does not on $t$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clarified. OP's confusion was that they though $\mathrm{V}(W_{t+dt} - W_t)$ depends on the running time $t$ rather than on the length of the time interval $dt$.